# How to fix a circular reference error by if condition in excel file?

Tags: excel

I have 3 A,B,C columns. I have put some formulas on B and C, something like this.

C1: `PRODUCT(A1:B1)`

B1: `SUM(A1+C1)`

But I have the circular reference warning.

and I change the formula with if condition to:

C1: `=IF(OR(ISBLANK(A1), ISBLANK(B1)), "", PRODUCT(A1:B1))`

B1: `=IF(OR(ISBLANK(A1), ISBLANK(C1)), "", A1+C1)`

But I still have the circular reference warning?
How do I avoid it?

Comment: Your problem is that the working variable of your IF statement is depending on that cell itself. It doesn't matter if the formula produces "", because if there's a formula there excels read it always as not blank. However, there's no way to get around this except more cleverly building your sheet because as long as B depends on C and C depends on B there's going to be a circle. Perhaps consider doing this calculation outside of that range to avoid the circular reference. ie: D1 = `If(or(isnumber(A1),isnumber(B1),isnumber(c1)), product(A1,B1)+(C1+A1))` (just a concept not a solution)

Comment: What is it you are trying to accomplish, exactly?

Comment: Are you sure that you didn't mean `B2 = A2 + C1`, i.e. the B column is the result (C) of the previous row plus the A value of the current row?

Comment: Why is this tagged `java`?

Answer (score 0):

Circular reference in this case means that the formulas you enter to the different cells depend on each other, so calculating them is not possible, because this would result in an endless loop.

In column C you want to see A*B.
In column B you want to see A+C.

So for example if column B is calculated as A+C, column C also would change because it is A*B. And that would mean column B to be recalculated as well because column C is changed and B should be A+C. And so on.

Spreadsheet softwares protect these kind of endless loops. And the reason for that is that these cause... Yes, **stackoverflow** :-)